# Left join with multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have these two tables:

```
sections - {id,title,description}
topics - {id,section_id,topictitle}
```

Each section has multiple topics in the topics table.

after reading and trying I found using left join is the right way

```
$sql = 'select * from sections left join topics on sections.id=topics.sections_id';
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$section = array();
$i=0;
while ($sections = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $sl = array(
        'title' => $sections['title'],
        'topics'=> $sections['topictitle'],
    );
    $section[$i++] = $sl;
}
```

Is this the right code to view all sections and topics??

Comment: @MahmoudGamal I want to view all sections and topic below each section in my pages.

Comment: it seems correct. Are facing any problem with this query!!!

Comment: The `mysql`-extension is outdated, not maintained anymore and will be marked as "deprecated" with PHP5.5. Use `PDO_MYSQL`, or `MySQLi` instead.

Comment: @KingCrunch oh thank you I'll change it in my main code thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're selecting from `sections` and joining `topics` so you will only ever get one topic linked to each section, it won't work if you have multiple topics linked to one section (which I think you have).

Do it the other way around - select from `topics` and join `sections`:

```
select * from topics left join sections on sections.id=topics.section_id
```

Keep in mind that if you have a section that has no topics linked, you won't get that section in your result set. If you want that then it's worth selecting the sections first.

Also, instead of incrementing like that, you can just push to the array - you don't need to manually manage the index:

```
// $section[$i++] = $sl;  // <-- your way

$section[] = $sl;
```

Comment: You are right when I tried my code first I inserted one topic for each section but after inserting multiple topics I got only the last topic for each section thank you very much